# Cant able to access String variable in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Trying access variable from session,request in Jquery success or error block...but
dont understand it shows null,the data in alert has complete HTML page,a help would be appreciable..:)

```
        <pre><code>$( document ).ready(function() {
                $("#becameAfan").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                   url:'subscribeTo.action',
                   dataType:'text',
                   success: function(data){
                               var status1=<%=request.getAttribute("verified")%>//null
                               var status=<%=session.getAttribute("verified")%>//its null
                       alert(data); //its giving xmlhttp object(entire page)
                       $("#fan").fancybox({
                            'enableEscapeButton' :true,
                            'hideOnOverlayClick' : true,
                            'showCloseButton' :true
                        }).trigger('click');
                           },
                           error: function(data) 
                           { 
                               var status=<%=session.getAttribute("verified")%>//its null
                       alert(data); //its giving xmlhttp object(entire page)
                               $.fancybox({
                                    href: "FanLoginPage.jsp",
                                    type: "iframe",
                                    'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
                                   'enableEscapeButton' : false,
                                  'showCloseButton' :true
                                });

                           }
                });
                return false;
                });});

    <pre><code>
INSIDE ACTION CLASS:
    session.setAttribute("status","verified");
    request.setAttribute("status","verified");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
                        out.print("SUCCESS");
    return SUCCESS;</pre></code>
```

Comment: try using ${request.verified} and ${session.verified}

Comment: put it in single quotes

Comment: like: '<%=session.getAttribute("verified")%>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.  The first being when your jsp file is served out, that's when the `<%=request.getAttribute("verified")%>` will be executed.  The code to set the attributes in your subscribeTo.action Action will NOT have fired at that time.

This can be verified by viewing the source of your page.  You will see the `null`s there before the success method on the ajax call ever fires.

Unfortunately, your javascript code will not have access to the session or request Objects.  You'll need to return something in the response from the action that the `success` method can look for.

Also, the `session.setAttribute` and `request.setAttribute` methods take the attribute name for the first argument, and the value for the second.  `session.getAttribute` and `request.getAttribute` take the attribute name.  So, you're setting an attribute named status, but getting an attribute named 'verified'.

```
<%=request.getAttribute("verified")%>
```

Comment: Oops that was testing i am accessing <%=request.getAttribute("status")%> but still gets null

Comment: As you told.. code will not have access to the session or request Objects. You'll need to return something in the response from the action that the success method can look for.  and this trick WORKED...i verified the user before loading the page itself which make some sense..:) thanks for advice

Comment: Glad you figured it out!